# Unable to get last connection info for SSH users (locked, no shell, public key) is there an alternative?

Tags: ssh, login, administration, last

I have several remote systems connecting to my server via SSH to establish tunnels.

They authenticate using a public key, their user is locked and their shell is set to /usr/sbin/nologin

It all works fine except with this setup the output from `last username` is empty for those accounts.

Is there a workaround to get last login info for those? I need the IP and connection time.

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `awk` on `/var/log/secure` or `/var/log/auth.log` (depending on the distro).

On my `CentOS 7` I get the following when I log in remotely:

```
Dec  8 21:58:20 <server hostname> sshd[8387]: Accepted publickey for gareth from 1.2.3.4 port 58392 ssh2: RSA 55:89:f9:20:db:c6:e0:6f:ff:d4:a7
```

The above was for interactive login but a similar entry was created for `sftp` login.

Therefore:

```
awk '/sshd.*Accepted/ {print $1,$2,$3,$9,$11}' /var/log/secure
```

should give you:

```
Dec 8 21:58:20 gareth 1.2.3.4
```